# Chequear que un objeto sea del tipo producto - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, clase, objeto

Lo siguiente es una cuestión conceptual:

Me encuentro haciendo unas prácticas con **JS** y **NodeJS**, y me topé con un punto de un ejercicio que solicita que una vez leido un archivo CSV y parseado a **JSON** se debe corroborar que los datos corresponden verdaderamente al tipo **Producto**. Esto se refiere a que debo corroborarlo mediante la creacion de una **clase** Producto y chequear que cada propiedad esté definida?

En un principio pensé comprobar el arreglo obtenido con un **for** para verificar que los datos existen y cumplen con el tipo de dato esperado, pero el ejercicio me señala que esa no es la solución (regular).

Los datos recibidos son los siguientes, a modo de ejemplo:

```
[
 {
  name: 'König', 
  description: '', 
  imageURL: 'https://image.jpg',
  brandName: 'Pilsener', 
  'attributes/style': 'classic', 
  'attributes/ibu': '5',
  'attributes/abv' : '2',
  price: '250',
  inStock: 'true' , 
  isVisible: 'true' , 
  launchDate: '' 
 },{
  name: 'Paulaner', 
  description: '', 
  imageURL: 'https://image.jpg',
  brandName: 'Paulaner', 
  'attributes/style': 'red', 
  'attributes/ibu': '8' ,
  'attributes/abv' : '4' ,
  price: '400' ,
  inStock: 'true' , 
  isVisible: 'false' , 
  launchDate: '' 
 } 
]
```

En un principio pensé esto:

```
const checkType = async data => {
    function Product(name, description, imageUrl, brandName, style, ibu, abv, price, inStock, isVisible, launchDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.style = style;
        this.ibu = ibu;
        this.abv = abv;
        this.price = price;
        this.inStock = inStock;
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
        this.launchDate = launchDate;
    }
    const check = [];
    for(let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
        const products = new Product(data[n].name, data[n].description, data[n].imageUrl,
            data[n].brandName, data[n]['attributes/style'], data[n]['attributes/ibu'],
            data[n]['attributes/abv'], data[n].price, data[n].inStock,
            data[n].isVisible, data[n].launchDate);
        check.push(products.name, products.description, products.imageUrl, products.brandName,
            products.style, products.ibu, products.abv, products.price, products.inStock,
            products.isVisible, products.launchDate);
    }
    const listProducts = [];
    if(!check.includes(undefined)) {
        for(let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
            if(data[n]['attributes/ibu'] === '' || data[n]['attributes/abv'] === '' || data[n].price === '' || data[n].inStock === '')
                return false;
            const prods = {
                name: data[n].name,
                description: data[n].description,
                imageUrl: data[n].imageUrl,
                brandName: data[n].brandName,
                attributes: {
                    style: data[n]['attributes/style'],
                    ibu: Number(data[n]['attributes/ibu']),
                    abv: Number(data[n]['attributes/abv'])
                },
                price: Number(data[n].price),
                inStock: data[n].inStock,
                isVisible: data[n].isVisible,
                launchDate: data[n].launchDate
            };
            listProducts.push(prods);
        }
        const list = await verify(listProducts);
        if(list) {
            write(list);
            return list;
        }
        return false;
    } return false;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este tipo de casos, TypeScript es cuando brilla bastante, al menos durante el entorno de desarrollo.

Tu propuesta de hacer una clase es lo primero que se me vino a la cabeza mientras leía tu pregunta.

Puedes recorrer el array, instanciar la clase pasándole como parámetro cada iteración y dentro del constructor, desestructurar dicho parámetro y si falta alguno, JS se encargará de lanzar un error.

El problema de esto es que comprobará que existen las claves, pero no el tipo, para eso tienes que validar el tipo, y esto ya lleva más trabajo. Puedes usar un módulo llamado [jsonschema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema) que sirve precisamente para eso, validar.

### Validación del contenido (sin instancia)

Sin embargo, veo que tu objeto está completamente formado por cadenas, así que es tan sencillo como recorrerlo y comprobar el tipo de cada valor, te dejo este ejemplo que he preparado basado en promesas:

```
const check = (object) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (const key in object) {
            if (typeof object[key] !== 'string') reject(`El tipo de ${object[key]} no es válido.`);
        }
        resolve();
    })
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    check(data[i])
        .then(() => console.log(`Objeto ${i} comprobado y validado.`))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Y si necesitas comprobar que la cadena no está vacía, cambia el if dentro de la función check por:

```
if (typeof object[key] !== 'string' || object[key].length == 0) reject(`El tipo de ${key} no es válido.`);
```

### Validación del contenido (con instancia)

Esta era la idea principal, aunque no valida el tipo, si comprueba que su longitud no sea 0.

Primero recorre el objeto y comprueba que la propiedad no esté vacía.
Después desestructura el objeto pasado como parámetro y lo asigna.

**Clase producto**

```
class Producto {
    constructor(data) {
        for (const key in data) {
            if (data[key] == "") throw new Error(`La propiedad ${key} está vacía.`);
        }
        const {
            name,
            description,
            imageURL,
            brandName,
            "attributes/style": attribStyle,
            "attributes/ibu": attribIbu,
            "attributes/abv": attribAbv,
            price,
            inStock, 
            isVisible, 
            launchDate
        } = data;
        Object.assign(this, { name, description, imageURL, brandName, attribStyle, attribIbu, attribAbv, price, inStock, isVisible, launchDate })
    };
}
```

**Iteración**

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(new Producto(data[i]));
}
```

Comment: Bárbaro! Igual al leer el fichero CSV me retorna todos los campos tipo string, por lo que objetivamente es fijarse que estén completos y ya. Ya que dice la consigna que entre el parseo y el guardado de los datos se debe corroborar que lo recibido realmente corresponde al tipo producto. Entonces con lo primero que mencionas, no es descabellado hacer una clase y validar de esa forma. Gracias Marcos por tu respuesta

Comment: He actualiza la respuesta, échale un ojo a ver si se adapta más a lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias Marcos!! Creo que si, que es lo más cercano a lo que tenía en mente y menos código del que yo ayer hice! Dejo actualizado el post con el código previo al que compartiste vos

Comment: He revisado por encima el código de tu edición y me ha llamado la atención que estás declarando funciones dentro de otra (checkType). Ten cuidado con estas cosas, hace tiempo leí que esto provoca fugas de memoria, no sé cómo de grave es porque no conozco JavaScript a tan bajo nivel, pero tenlo en cuenta para otros proyectos ;)

Comment: Genial, la verdad que excelente el aporte. Muchas gracias. Más que apuntado